# User managed to post a question twice within the same second of each other

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Somehow a user managed to accidentally post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181354/why-do-you-define-a-rule-twice-in-prolog) twice:

[image]

I may be missing something, but this shouldn't be able to happen, should it? They should be subjected to a 45 minute cooldown between questions shouldn't they?

Comment: I posted it here because this doesn't seem to be SO specific.

Comment: If the content is exactly the same, you can close vote one these questions as duplicate. But usually this shouldn't be possible to happen, I agree.

Comment: Seems to be a dupe, although there's so answer in the linked post.

Comment: I voted to reopen, this question since there's no answer in the accepted duplicate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wasn't sure what the protocol was there honestly: if any answers should all be consolidated on the existing older, unanswered post, or here.

Comment: Duplicates never depend on the questions age. It could happen that the older question might be closed as duplicate of this one.

Comment: These questions are so close that it's likely to be a race condition; the linked question isn't (or it's a very slow race).

Comment: Why was this marked as an exact duplicate, posting two questions before the time-limit and a question being double-posted, are different scenarios are they not?

Comment: @Mark Honestly, I accepted the dupe suggestion because I got a stressful email from my school right before the suggestion was made, and didn't feel like defending it not being a dupe at that moment.

Comment: It's a prolog question, and Stack Overflow backtracked while processing it. *Rimshot.wav*