# I'd like the reopen notification removed from my notification history if possible (/ bug report)

Tags: support, bug, android-app, notification-bar

About 10 minutes ago, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339640/user-managed-to-post-a-question-twice-within-the-same-second-of-each-other) question of mine was reopened after being closed as a dupe. This gave me a notification that I've never seen before:

> Hooray, this question was reopened! Anyone can answer it now.

The problem is, ever since I got this notification, opening the notification tab in the SE Android app causes the app to crash. I've been active on the app for the last like hour, and the crashing started at the same time as the notification. It seems like the app doesn't know how to handle something about that type of notification.

Since I know better than to ask about fixing the app, I'm wondering if I can simply get that notification purged from my account? I'd rather not have the app crash on me for the next week or two until that notification ages away.

Thank you.

---

Android 9, Note 8, App Version 1.0.95

Comment: Ha, it's moved down now and crashes if I scroll at all, but at least I can see new notifications.